# HOW to get value of Button without form tag

Tags: php, button

```
<button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-2" value="<?php echo $row->p_id;?>;">Read more</button>
```

i wanna get value of this button
any idea?

Comment: with javascript & ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible unless you do an Ajax call on a button click and than POST the data from the Ajax call.

If you do not have a form. There is no data set, and you won't have a postback.

If you just want to have a link and use that data. Just use a GET to send the data to the next page.

Comment: can u give me example of that?